# wordpress plugin installation

Tags: wordpress, plugins

I am learning wordpress. Now I want to install a simple photo gallery plugin. For that I have downloaded plugin from internet. Now how to integrate that so that I can find from the front-end in a particular position.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Your theme should have specific areas to put the plugins in.
If not You should open the php file of the template that you want to display the plugin in and add this code:

```
if ( !function_exists('dynamic_sidebar') || !dynamic_sidebar('Your plugin name') ) :
endif;
```

Now, open your functions.php and add this:

```
if ( function_exists('register_sidebar') ) {
    register_sidebar( array(
        'name'          => 'Your plugin name',
        'id'            => 'login-widget',
        'before_widget' => '<section class="login-widget">',
        'after_widget'  => '</section>',
        'before_title'  => '<span class="widget-title">',
        'after_title'   => '</span>')
    );
}
```

after you are done with that, you can go to your administrator page, click on Appearance -> Widgets and then drag the plugin name from the list to the dock named "Your plugin name"

Comment: I download wordpress-flash-page-flip.zip and install this plugin. Now one link in the admin control panel is showing named as "Flash Page Flip" and in the plugins menu "Wordpress Flash Page Flip" is showing which has not any setting option.But there is no option for the newly added plugin in the Appearance->Widgets. So how to solve that?